# How to remove an execution data from camunda using workflows

Tags: java, camunda

I have a bpmn process that once starts and continues its execution forever based on the Timer cycle event. There is no end event for it.
I had recently done few changes with the workflow and made a redeployment to camunda. Since the existing processes are already running I need an option to stop it which I am finding difficult to do through workflow.
How can I stop existing execution if a new workflow started its execution? Can we achieve that using workflow itself? REST / Java coding cannot be done to achieve this.

I have another question regarding an order by query in camunda.
From the above scenario, i ended up seeing quite a few similar variables in variable table. How can i get the latest variable out of it? orderByActivityInstanceId is the only option i saw, which i feel is not reliable.

Comment: You should split your two questions  into two post, each with a meaningful title. You are asking about terminating a process in an endless loop and about sorting of a query. There is nothing about removing data in your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use other events (conditional, message or signal) to react to the situation in which you want to stop the looping process. You can for instance add an event-based sub process with a interrupting message start event to your process model.

[image]

To your second point: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.15/reference/rest/history/activity-instance/get-activity-instance-query/

> **sortBy**    Sort the results by a given criterion. Valid values are
> activityInstanceId, instanceId, executionId, activityId, activityName,
> activityType, startTime, endTime, duration, definitionId, occurrence
> and tenantId. Must be used in conjunction with the sortOrder
> parameter.

https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.15/reference/rest/variable-instance/get/
is another option

Answer (score 0):

To stop all the active process instances in Camunda, you can do this by calling a Camunda REST API or by Java Coding.

**Using REST API**

[Activate/Suspend Process Instance By Id](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.8/reference/rest/process-instance/put-activate-suspend-by-id/)

**Using Java**

[Suspend Process Instances](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.15/user-guide/process-engine/process-engine-concepts/#suspend-process-instances)

> If you would like to suspend all process instances of a given process definition, you can use the method suspendProcessDefinitionById(...) of theRepositoryService and specify the suspendProcessInstances option.

Comment: Do we have an option within the workflow, I mean without involving an execution/task listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, i appreciate your response @amine & @rob.
I got it resolved using a signal event. Every time when a new process is deployed it triggers a signal event that will stop the recursion.

To sort the data there are options within camunda. But I had done it differently.
If there is more than one variable, I fetch them using versionTag from the process definition table.